# Redirect to current page (not reload) on click

Tags: jquery, redirect

I'm needing to redirect to the current page when a certain button is clicked.

I have checked other similar questions but the answers seem to always be to "reload" the page.

Reloading is not an option as the form will be resubmitted if the page is reloaded.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does redirect to the current page w/o reloading mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter I read other similar questions but the solutions given were to reload the page through js/jquery. I wanted to make that distinction so that I didn't get those answers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's say we have this button: `<button id="button1">Click me!</button>`.
Now we want to make it redirect to itself.

We can add a `<script>` tag with the following code:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
   window.location.replace(window.location.href);
});
```

Make sure you have jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this -**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  window.location.href="yourlink";
});
```

Comment: This button is in the footer of all pages. Putting a static link won't work in my case. This is why I mentioned that it must redirect to the "current" page